# Web.py cannot find files

Tags: python, html, web.py

I've an web-server that is written with python and web.py.
I wanna make it a daemon. So there is a linux (debian) OS.
I've written a code. So now this web-server starts as the daemon, I can see it in process list and reach main page in my browser.

I used web.py module and there is a render technology in this module. This technology uses html templates to create a web page (html code mixed with python). In this templates I use standard html code to add css styles and pictures. A folder with such content is placed in location of the daemon run file.

So my daemon loads this templates. But there is no css or images. I've checked an execution of template code (enter some text strings) - everything is alright.

So there is a problem: why this html cannot reach other content and how to repare this?

One important thing: previously that was just the web-server (not the daemon) and not-a-daemon version works (I keep a copy) well! All problems appear when I start the daemon.

Hope for your help!

there are some code parts:

```
#Daemon start file
class Hive(Daemon):
    def run(self):
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    daemon = Hive('/tmp/daemon-example.pid')
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            sys.argv[1] = '8080'
            daemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.restart()
        else:
            print "Unknown command"
            sys.exit(2)
        sys.exit(0)
else:
    print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(2)
--------------------------------------------------------
#home.html - template that realizes a part of main page and loads some
#picture. I've checked the "if" operator (that activates the <img> tag) - server
#executes it. On my page I see a place for picture (standard form when
#page cannot find the picture to download).
$def with (clients)
<!-- отображение данных о клиентах в базе: ip-адрес, состояние, привилегии
-->
<style type='text/css'>
    .client { height: 40px; }
    .client_current  { border-left: 4px solid lightgreen; }
</style>

<!--<div><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'
style='margin-right: 10px;'></span><a href='#' class='_sh'
data-active='1' data-remote='.online'>Online</a></div>-->
<div style="min-height: 100px;">
<div>Online</div>
<div class='online'>
$code:
    offline = False
$for client in clients:
    $if not offline and not client.online:
        $code:
            offline = True
        </div><div>Offline</div><div class='offline'>
    $if client.admin:
        <div class='client client-admin' style='clear: both; padding: 4px;'>
    $else:
        <div class='client' style='clear: both; padding: 4px;'>
    <a href='#client$client.id' onclick='return activateClient(this);' id='client$client.id' class='client_item'>
        <div class='img' style='float: left;'>
        $if client.icon:
            <img src='/powerhive-0.3.beta/static/img/wait.png' />
        $else:
            <img src='/powerhive-0.3.beta/static/img/wait.png' />
        </div>
        <div style='float: left; font-size: 10px; margin: 2px;'>
            <div style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;'>$client.ip</div>
            $client.info
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I've found the answer!
I added to the url this string: `'/(js|css|img)/(.*)', 'static',`.
The class static was implemented earlier. This class is alike:

```
class static:
    def GET(self, media, file):
        try:
            f = open(media+'/'+file, 'r')
            return f.read()
        except:
            return '404'
```

And the after that (the most escited part):
If my daemon had couldn't access my static folder, I replaced the source parameter of my image (and so js files) to: `http://localhost/static/img/wait.png`

That's it! May be that's rude but that works ;)